# How to find out what sent the email

Tags: apex, email, workflow, email-template, configuration

One of the users has received an email containing data from my ORG with a link to a task and he is not supposed to get it. I'm trying to figure out what has sent it.

I have reviewed all of the 600 email templates and none matches. 
There is no code that matches it. I could not find a workflow that might have done it.

Can someone suggest me where else to look?

Comment: I would say start looking at the email logs first and confirm if salesforce has definitely emailed the user. If you see a log of the transaction then take the internal Id of the message and follow up with salesforce. I havent gone down the path of following up and seeing what content / why the email was sent out.

Comment: Also take a look at this post on how to understand and read the email logs from salesforce. http://opfocus.com/how-to-find-and-make-sense-of-salesforce-email-logs/

Comment: I have confirmed from the logs that it is sent from SF. Now the next challenge is to find out, somehow, how it was sent and by what

Comment: You should be able to get the sender info from the email logs. Now getting the body of the email will be a challenge

Comment: I already knew who the sender is, but my issue is that I do not know what is sending it. Workflow, .. code, .... or what ever. 
I also have an example of the mail, just a screenshot, but no templates match the mail

Comment: Best would be to open a case with salesforce and try to figure out simultaneously what is triggering the email out to the user. Also keep checking if the emails are sent out at specific time in a day, if so there is a batch script/ time based workflow triggering the email. If it is being sent random then a trigger./workflow is the culprit.

Comment: Can you provide some or all of the email text? It may be helpful to see it...sometimes searching for something like that can be tricky.

Comment: it's prod data, ...  The top of it is styled, but the rest looks like plaintext.
I have double checked the email templates and can confirm that none of them was used.
Also, I looked further into the past, and it is not repeating. no chron pattern

Comment: there are system emails sent via config settings; perhaps you could post in a screen shot the email you see (obscuring sensitive data). The Community might recognize the source

Comment: In the end, it turned out, it was a workflow email alert. It was harder to find it because it was activated during the lead activation process